# How to make a checkbox array with PrimeFaces?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I need to make a checkbox array as follows

[image]

I have this class java

```
    private Map<String, String> offices;
private Map<String, String> services;
private Map<String, Map<String, Boolean>> officeServices;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    offices = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    offices.put("o1", "office1");
    offices.put("o2", "office2");
    offices.put("o3", "office3");
    services = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    services.put("s1", "service1");
    services.put("s2", "service2");
    services.put("s3", "service3");
    officeServices = new HashMap<>();
    for (String office : offices.keySet()) {
        officeServices.put(office, new HashMap<String, Boolean>());
    }

}

public void submit() {
    for (Entry<String, Map<String, Boolean>> entry : officeServices.entrySet()) {
        String office = entry.getKey();
        Map<String, Boolean> services = entry.getValue();
        System.out.println(office + ": " + services);
    }
}
```

I have two maps I go through and add one inside the other

is the following jsf

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Office</th>
        <ui:repeat value="#{bean.services.values().toArray()}" var="service">
            <th>#{service}</th>
        </ui:repeat>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <ui:repeat value="#{bean.offices.entrySet().toArray()}" var="office">
        <tr>
            <td>#{office.value}</td>
            <ui:repeat value="#{bean.services.keySet().toArray()}" var="service">
                <td><p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{bean.officeServices[office.key][service]}" /></td>
            </ui:repeat>
        </tr>
    </ui:repeat>
</tbody>
```

This works, but there are fields that I need to load with the true checkbox, is this possible and how?

Comment: Does it work with a plain jsf selectBooleanCheckbox?

Comment: yes, it works as a simple selectBooleanBox

Comment: That is weird so it works in the code above if you just replace the `p:`with an `h:`??? Which PF version?

Comment: I'm using the version 6.1

Comment: "there are fields that I need to load with the true checkbox" just do `officeServices.get("officeKey").put("serviceKeyWhichShouldBeTrueForThisOffice", true)` in your `init` method.

Comment: I did not understand

Comment: officeServices.get( office ).put( service, true );>>>return null pointer

Comment: @RenanW.B.Gonç a similar question was a few days ago. See my answer to that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49340632/880619

Comment: Perfect, it works